# C# WPF - Change control content when another control event occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm quite new to WPF and MVVM and I'm trying to create a custom `WindowChrome` with all the standard `Window` features. I'm struggling with the Maximize/Minimize window `Button` content: I want the content to change when the user double clicks the `WindowChrome` bar, in order to show the right icon:

[image]

When I double click the bar, the result should be:

[image]

I managed to change the content with the Button `Triggers`, but how can I change it when another control event occurs?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not completely sure when you say another control event. But in WPF for common event handling is normally implemented using  Commands (Save , Cut ,Copy , Paste etc).  ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview )

Comment: I would want to do a trigger on the window's `WindowState` property. This is state, not an event. The question, of course, is how you're implementing any of this. I don't see any hints about that.

Comment: @Viju In this case, when the Window top bar is DoubleClicked, the Maximize button content must change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the Button a Style with triggers that set the content based on the value of `Window.WindowState`. This isn't an event. The button reflects the current state of the window.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
            Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- I don't know if you're using a Path or what -->
                    <Path Stroke="White" Data="..." />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
            Value="Normal">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- I don't know if you're using a Path or what -->
                    <Path Stroke="White" Data="..." />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It would be wiser to set the Template of the button instead, because there’s only one copy of each of those Paths, and if you reuse the style twice, they can’t be shared.

If there's some reason why this won't work with your code, show me your code.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, a way to set properties referring to another type property. I think I still have to work on WPF a lot more... I was trying to set the button content by implementing every single event that could change the window state. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Belfed Glad to help. In WPF, we don't use events much in managing visual state of controls. Always look for a property that indicates the *state* you're interested in -- Button has `IsPressed`, etc. etc. -- and write a trigger. `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` is another thing you'll see, but no need to go there at this point.